# How to use two where condition?

Tags: mysql

When i am trying to run these query

```
Select * from products p, products_to_categories pc  
where p.product_id = pc.product_id and pc.category_id ='.$category_id.' 
where p.status=1
```

getting following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where p.status=1' at line 1

Comment: Yes, that would be bad... Don't use a `where` after a `where` like that.

Comment: Try either `where p.product_id = pc.product_id and pc.category_id ='.$category_id.' AND p.status=1` OR `where (p.product_id = pc.product_id and pc.category_id ='.$category_id.') OR p.status=1` depending on which is true.

Comment: You can only have `WHERE` once in a query.  Use `AND` or `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For additonal conditions use `and`/`or` instead of another `where`.

```
Select * 
from products p
inner join products_to_categories pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pc.category_id = '.$category_id.' 
and p.status = 1
```

Besides you can use the join syntax.

Comment: @echo_Me: Of course I could. I could quit any time I like. (Hands shaking)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use where once. Then it should be followed with AND

YOU CODE:

```
 WHERE p.product_id = pc.product_id AND pc.category_id ='.$category_id.' AND p.status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause consists of only one WHERE followed by concatenated conditions (concatenated by the use of ANDs, ORs and parentheses to force precedence between said conditions).

```
WHERE p.product_id = pc.product_id
AND pc.category_id = '.$category_id.'
AND p.status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from products p 
inner join products_to_categories pc
on p.product_id = pc.product_id
where pc.category_id ='.$category_id.' 
and p.status=1
```

To get much more perfomance of statement (especially if you have many rows) i recommend you to use `JOIN` clause. Its fastest approach as possible and also against yours more human-readable.

For selection are usually used keywords `AND`, `OR` You should read [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp).